# Lost android phone, shows no active devices

Tags: lost-phone

Lost an android phone. This is what shows:

[image: Find your Phone]

I tried getting the map at android.com/find

This is what is shows:

[image: android.com/find]

Help please.

Comment: Whenever you factory reset a phone, it is deactivated from the respective google account and anyone who doesn't want to return it, resets the phone.  Sorry to say but this is the possible case with your phone. I've lost 3 phones (+ 5-6 of my knowns) and literally these things never work. Because In India, people resets your phone the very same moment they get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Google [account support](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6160491?hl=en),

> **Make sure your device can be found**
>
> After you sign in to a Google Account on an >Android device, Find My Device is on by default.
>
> To use Find My Device, a lost Android device must be:
>
> - Turned on
> - Signed in to a Google Account
> - Connected to mobile data or Wi-Fi
> - Visible on Google Play
> - Location turned on
> - Find My Device turned on
>
> Lost Android Wear devices must also be running Android Wear 2.0 and up.

Unfortunately, if any of these settings are turned off you might not be able to locate your device. Given that you do not have access to your device my best guess is one of these is not on.