# "Find My Phone" shows "No active devices"

Tags: lost-phone

I am having an issue very similar to [this one](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/184390/lost-android-phone-shows-no-active-devices). However, all the settings noted in the accepted answer are turned on for me. I have used find my phone in the past (though not for a while). I don't know how or when it changed but I haven't had this problem before.

I am able to see my phone on my account's devices, but the options there are not very useful:

[image]

As per [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/217983/find-my-phone-shows-no-active-devices) I also installed the Find My Device app on the phone. I can see my phone there, but I don't understand how that's useful (I could only find my phone from my phone if I have my phone already). The phone still doesn't show up on the web. Any help/ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Try 1.signing out of your phone and after a while signing in 2. Different browser 3.[this](https://amp.reddit.com/r/AndroidQuestions/comments/dnrnk2/find_my_device_says_no_active_phones/) 4.[and this](https://support.google.com/accounts/thread/18897206?hl=en)

Comment: Check on your device under Settings -> Security if it shows that "Find My Device" is active.